# Tensors and Nuclear/Fredholm Operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, tensor-products, locally-convex-spaces

For a locally convex Hausdorff spaces $E$, consider the canonical map
$$\overline{\psi}:E^\prime \hat{\otimes}_\pi E \longrightarrow L(E_\sigma)$$
that maps the projective tensor product to the space of weakly continuous maps on $E$ (note, that if $E$ is Banach spaces, then the latter is just the space $L(E)$ of bounded linear operators).

The question whether this map is injective is well-known to be connected to the *approximation property*. For example:

- If $E$ is a Banach space, then $E$ has the approximation property if and only if $\overline{\psi}$ is injective.
- If $E$ has is a complete locally convex space with a fundamental system of absolutely convex neighborhoods $U$ of zero such that every Banach space $E_U$ has the approximation property, then $\overline{\psi}$ is injective.

These statements can be found in Köthe's book "Topologcial Vector Spaces II".

**Question:** If $E$ is complete and has the approximation property, is it false/true/not known whether $\overline{\psi}$ is injective in general?

**Edit**: A locally convex space $X$ is said to satisfy the *approximation property*, if the space of finite rank operators is dense in the space $L_c(X)$, the set of continuous linear operators with the topology of uniform convergence on precompact sets. <s>For Banach spaces, this is equivalent to saying that the finite rank operators are dense in the compact operators with respect to the operator norm.</s>

Comment: It seems to be $\textit{the approximation propery}$ is not really defined in your post.

Comment: I added the definition in the post.

Comment: What is the motivation for this? You started to work with non-nuclear spaces?

Comment: It seems that Grothendieck and also Köthe deal with this characterization of the approximation property ("condition de biunivocite") only in the case of Banach spaces. I suspect that the reason for this is that only in this case you have a "canonical" topology on the dual. In the locally convex case, which topology on $E'$ do you consider to define $E'\hat{\otimes}_\pi E$?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the equivalence, for a Banach space $X$, between (i) the space of finite rank operators is dense in $L_\sigma(X)$ and (ii) the space of finite rank operators is dense in $K(X)$ for the operator norm? (i)$\implies$(ii) is clear, but I always thought that the converse is not true...

Comment: @Bombyx mori: Yes, like Banach spaces.

Comment: @Jochen Wengenroth: I thought of this with the weak topology, but maybe it should rather be the strong topology?

Comment: @Mikael de la Salle: No, it is claimed at various places, but I couldn't find a proof, so i striked the text for the time being.

Comment: @MatthiasLudewig: Do you know a good reference on projective/injective tensor product of Banach spaces? I am not familiar with the book you listed, maybe it is a good reference, just I do not know.

Comment: I do not think that it is a good idea to take the weak$^*$ topology for defining $E'\hat{\otimes}_\pi E$: The completion of $E'_\sigma$ consists of ALL linear functionals on $E$. Perhaps the best choice would be the topology of uniform convergence on all absolutely convex compact sets.